# Python open csv file copy to variable close file use variable?

Tags: python

I am trying to read a csv file, copy it, close the file and use the copy.  I need to move away from the with or csv.reader block. after hours of searching i found this:

```
fr = open('my_symbols.csv', 'r')
csv.reader(fr)
my_symbol_list = deepcopy(fr)
fr.close()
```

But that does not work either.  Anybody have any hints or suggestions?  There must be a simple answer rigth?

Thanks in advance

Skip

Comment: What, excactly, do you want to end up with here?  You're not reading any of the CSV file.  Do you expect a dataframe?  Do you want a list of rows?  Please show us what data structure you'd like to have.

Comment: And what does `deepcopy()` refer to?

Comment: From what I read it is supposed to make a duplicate copy the object returned from the reader.  In this case the csv.file is a list of ticker symbols I just need to copy them to a list and have available outside the reader.  If that makes sense. my_symbol_list = ['XLE, XLF, XLK, ......]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#make variable outside of 'with'
filelines = []

with open('my_symbols.csv','r') as fr:
    filelines = fr.readlines()

#after with (file is now closed), use the variable.
#you may need to split up the lines further in to columns
print(filelines[0])
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it.